# BNF Grammar Ambiguity

Tags: grammar, bnf

I was recently thinking of the following BNF

```
A -> x | yA | yAzA

where x,y,z are terminals.
```

I'm pretty sure this grammar is ambiguous, but how would one make it unambiguous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A grammar is ambiguous if a particular string can have more than one parse tree.  In your language the string `yyxzx` can have either of these two parse trees:

```
    A                  A
   / \                /|\`\
  y   A              y A z A
     /|\`\            / \   \
    y A z A          y   A   x
      |   |              |
      x   x              x
```

Therefore the grammar is ambiguous.

This actually is equivalent to the notorious "if/then/else" ambiguity in C-like languages, where `y=if`, `z=else`, and `x=statement`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else.  I would recommend checking out that page for ideas on how to get around this problem.